# Basic Kong Infrastructure

Tags: kong

I have a very generic question that I can't find an answer about Kong. I couldn't find in the official documents a proper description of the suggested overall architecture. In particular, it is not clear to me how it should work with the consumer registration.

- The call to create a consumer looks public, so anyone could create one and it would be up to my upstream services to understand if that user is really one of mine or some random one
- Say that I wan to use JWT auth plugin, then when a user registers I should give him his own secret so he will be able to compute his token. I mean, my services know a new user is registering and should query kong to get the info about his secret. In this process I see my user's secret in plain, is this the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: You must put the admin port behind a firewall for internal usage only.

Answer (score 2):

Rossi,

- I wouldn't expose kong's admin port to the public, that would prevent that kind of call you are worried.
- I would never send the secret in plain, I prefer not to send the secret at all. If you have something like a resource owner system interacting with kong would be better you can use it to validate a password before accessing the user's secret and then generate the token and sent it back to the user. I think this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

you should not expose the kong admin interface publicly.
you should access it manually by logging to the kong server console or automatically via a local service installed on the same server which authenticates incoming admin requests and allows only you to create users.